# Localize entries in matrix which are similar (not necessarily identical) to nearest neigbours?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, search

This is a raw idea I have in my mind, but I'm pretty sure there is a specific name for the following type of algorithm or math concept? Can somebody give me pointers which area to look deeper into if I want to implement something like this:

Say I have a [100x100] matrix of numbers. My goal is to find those positions in this matrix where the surrounding entries are very similar (e.g. only differ from each other by 0.1).

In other words, I would go through each entry in this matrix and check whether the nearest neighbors are close (0.1 distance) to this specific entry in question. In the end I want a list of those entry positions where this distance criterion is satisfied.

The goal is to use this algorithm to find location in this matrix where entries are homogenous, similar. I want to implement this in Javascript.

Comment: I think you should maybe look on knn or dbscan if you want to find the density in specific place on some relatable data, here some information about it-> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN

Comment: You can try running a BFS from a position and keep track of levels/distance.

Comment: The naive solution would seem to be to iterate the matrix and check each neighbor. This would be O(n) time so optimization would seem to be premature.

That said, if you want a broader goal of determining "areas of homogeneity" this seems similar to the classic paint fill function, though not exactly the same, as, if you proceed naively, an element can belong to a group according to one neighbor but not another. However this seems like a reasonable preprocessing technique to determine candidates.